# how to stop or limit select after selecting top 100 row?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, limit

I have a query like this -

```
SELECT c.msisdn,SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink+c.dataVolumeUpLink) AS datasum 
FROM cdr c 
WHERE c.eveDate>='2013-10-29'
GROUP BY c.msisdn 
ORDER BY datasum DESC;
```

This one taking 4 minutes. I have an index on evedate.

CDR table contains 2400000 records for each day from '2013-10-01' to '2013-10-30'. But I want to select only first 100 records. How I am suppose to optimize this query.

I have used limit clause but there is no benefit of it.

So please let me know how I can optimize this query.

Thank you.

Comment: Adding  `LIMIT 0, 100` should work. As far as I know limit will stop the query after the first 100 rows that meet the requirements are met.

Comment: Because your `datesum` field is dynamically calculated it must be explicitly ordered, this takes time - no way to get around that. The `limit` will not help you here. If you were to create a view of the query and then select with the limit you would probably see a performance gain.

Comment: Ah yes, that's the best option here. Creating a view will do the job. Good thinking @BoristheSpider

Comment: @BoristheSpider this is correct, but i can't create 7 view for 7 different queries. So is there any other way apart from limit and view I can make query faster?

Answer (score 3):

you just put

```
LIMIT 100
```

after .... ORDER BY datasum DESC *here*;

like .... ORDER BY datasum DESC LIMIT 100;

Answer (score 1):

If records are distributed evenly, one day would have 80k rows. `GROUP BY` operation over 80k might not take 4 minute (I guess)

I'm not sure you have following index:

```
INDEX(eveDate, msisdn)
```

with above index, records are sorted by eveDate and msisdn so `GROUP BY` operation is optimized. i.e, same msisdns are located same block. I guess following query is faster than your query.

**Q1**

```
SELECT x.msisdn, SUM(datasum)
FROM
(
    SELECT c.msisdn AS msisdn,
        SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink+c.dataVolumeUpLink) AS datasum 
    FROM cdr c 
    WHERE c.eveDate>='2013-10-29'
    GROUP BY eveDate, c.msisdn 
) x
GROUP BY x.msisdn
ORDER BY SUM(datasum)
LIMIT 100;
```

or something like this.

**Q2**

```
SELECT c.msisdn SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink+c.dataVolumeUpLink) AS datasum 
FROM cdr c 
WHERE c.eveDate>='2013-10-29'
GROUP BY c.msisdn 
ORDER BY 100;
```

above query is simpler, but same msisdn can be located in another eveDate. so benefit from `INDEX(eveDate, msisdn)` is a little. If you disk has large free space, following INDEX makes execution only INDEX scan. no need for data. all required is in INDEX

```
INDEX(eveDate, msisdn, dataVolumeDownLink, dataVolumeUpLink)
```

### UPDATED

hmm, If data is append only, and appended data is never changed. I wonder if make summary table for every day.

```
CREATE TABLE summary(eveDate, msisdn, datasum, INDEX(eveDate, msisdn);
```

and run following query every night via cronjob

```
INSERT INTO summary
SELECT NOW() c.msisdn,SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink+c.dataVolumeUpLink) AS datasum 
FROM cdr c 
WHERE c.eveDate = NOW()
GROUP BY c.msisdn
```

then your query would be very simple.

```
SELECT msisdn, SUM(datasum) as datasum
FROM summary
WHERE eveDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: I can't add more index on this table because insertion rate is too much. And I have other queries too, so i can not add indexes for each query. But if there is any way you can help me how to deal with comparison condition, because when I am going to use date a month ago, this queries(i have other queries too) gonna take lot of time.
thank you.

Comment: and what is -
in first query -> ORDER BY SUM(datasum)?
because datasum is already a summerized column.
in second query -> ORDER BY 100??

Comment: @Aamir0731 inner query of Q1 is "GROUP BY eveDate, msisdn" or need to SUM() outer SELECT. this assumes there is INDEX(eveDate, msisdn)

Comment: means there is no way to make this query faster without adding index :( ok let me  add composite index according to the query and check the output.

Comment: @Aamir0731 Just my personal opinions. I hope Someone can help you.

Comment: @Aamir0731 People who has very good optimization skill come here in 3 hours. Let us wait them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.msisdn,SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink+c.dataVolumeUpLink) AS datasum 
FROM cdr c 
WHERE c.eveDate>='2013-10-29'
GROUP BY c.msisdn 
ORDER BY datasum DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.msisdn,SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink+c.dataVolumeUpLink) AS datasum 
FROM 
(select * from cdr where eveDate>='2013-10-29' limit 100) as c 

GROUP BY c.msisdn 
ORDER BY datasum DESC;
```

Small change from Larry's answer

 
Not completely sure if I understood the question correctly 

 
This would first take the first 100 records and do the calculation on that. 
So the final result may be less that 100 rows, based on the group by clause

EDIT : 

 As per your clarification, you will need to add an index on c.msisdn  and add a limit clause at the end 
 Remove the order by clause and put an outer query just to have the records ordered by

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
SELECT c.msisdn,SUM(c.dataVolumeDownLink+c.dataVolumeUpLink) AS datasum 
FROM cdr c 
WHERE c.eveDate>='2013-10-29'
GROUP BY c.msisdn limit 100) a 
ORDER BY a.datasum DESC;
```

add an index on c.msisdn

Comment: No, I don't want to perform operation on first 100. Otherwise output will be wrong. If is there any way to select top 100(from all records) records first from query(in my question), please let me know.